# Facebook messaging

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have set my Facebook account on all my devices as "Turn Chat Off."  I like to be on Facebook in peace. I have NOT installed the Messenger App.  However, it seems like my friends using the Messenger App are still seeing me as online in the Chat box in Messenger when I am online.
Or is there some other way that I am visible either through the Messenger App or the Facebook App that people can get around the Turn Chat Off option and still detect you as online.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, when you are turned off for chat on all devices, your friends should not be able to see you online. So, either by mistake you were not actually turned off for chat, or there is some glitch in Facebook.

You should cross check this, may be have your friend's Facebook account opened in front of you to see if you are really shown online, and then you may try to file a complaint somewhere in Facebook help.

Comment: also there might be few minutes delay after turning chat off until you will appear offline for everyone.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem, just posted new question about it. My Son didn't even know this until I showed it to him (early 20's lol, he usually knows before I do) but, if you click on a message to or from any friend, look @the top left, under their name, it shows "last ative" or "active" when you are on.
I don't have ANY Facebook app installed, I go online then log into Facebook. I also, have chat turned off....STILL shows in messages, NOT talking about CHAT, just clicking on messages, it shows for many. Not all, some show "mobile" but, many show active or last seen.
Lose of ALL PRIVACY